# Synchronized file reading of the same file c

Tags: c++, file, pointers, synchronization, children

***Background***

the of background of the project I am building for this operating systems course. This project will execute a program named program1 then that program will create 9 pipes one semaphore, one shared memory which counts the numbers of characters that have been read and then also takes in command line arguments for the filename. The first program will also after creating everything else spawn 9 children and pass them all the previous information, one pipe going from program1 to the specific child, the semaphore, the shared memory location, the filename.

Each child will have synchronized access to a file, shared memory. Each child will then read 1-10 characters at random and then increment the shared memory by that amount. The children then will send the name of the program that currently has access and the characters that were read and write them into the pipe. If they get to end of line they will then also write the total number of read character read in the same string that gotten written into the pipe. When the specific child does this it will then pass the execution to program1 for execution.

When program one gets execution privileges by the semaphore then it will read the string sent through all the nonblocking pipes. Then writes that string to the output file and then frees the semaphore for any of the children to use again till the eof has been reached.
***Question***

> Now that I have told you how the program is going to run, I have a question. How exactly do I keep track of position of a file pointer and its location in the file between all of the processes reading the same file. Am I able to pass the file pointer itself to the children and use that? Or will I not be able to pass it because of different memory spaces?
>
> I'm guessing what I probably could do is access the shared memory and
>   get the file position since the shared memory holds an int value of
>   how many characters would have been read. That being said, I feel like
>   that would be unnecessary overhead and computation that could be
>   avoided if I can do it a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Consider reducing your question to the topic you actually want an answer to. [Look here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Okay, as the post states it is the background of the project that I am working on and then in the quoted area gives the question that is directly related to the problem that I am asking about.